# Curl работает только под php-cli

Tags: php, curl, macos, homebrew

Один и тот же скрипт, если запустить через CLI, то все работает хорошо

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $certPass);
```

А если через Web получаю ошибку

> SSL: Can't load the certificate "*.p12" and its private key: OSStatus
>   -61

Понятное дело что скорее всего дело в конфигурации, которая для CLI отличается.
Но я начинающий пользователь OSX(Sierra), поэтому еще не разобрался с конфигурациями.

Все ставилось через **homebrew**
`php -i` возвращает следующее

```
PHP Version => 5.6.27

PHP API => 20131106
PHP Extension => 20131226
Zend Extension => 220131226
Zend Extension Build => API220131226,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20131226,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => enabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => enabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
Openssl default config => /usr/local/etc/openssl/openssl.cnf

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.43.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => No
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-apple-darwin15.0
SSL Version => SecureTransport
ZLib Version => 1.2.5
```

А `phpinfo()` такое

```
PHP Version 5.6.24

PHP API 20131106
PHP Extension   20131226
Zend Extension  220131226
Zend Extension Build    API220131226,NTS
PHP Extension Build API20131226,NTS
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Signal Handling    enabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  enabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk
Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.43.0
Age 3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
CharConv    No
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN No
IPv6    Yes
krb4    No
Largefile   Yes
libz    Yes
NTLM    Yes
NTLMWB  Yes
SPNEGO  Yes
SSL Yes
SSPI    No
TLS-SRP No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    x86_64-apple-darwin15.0
SSL Version SecureTransport
ZLib Version    1.2.5

OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.2j 26 Sep 2016
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.2h 3 May 2016
Openssl default config  /usr/local/etc/openssl/openssl.cnf
```

Куда копать? Может кто знает из-за чего могло не работать? Может как-то можно синхронизировать cli и web версии

Comment: может быть дело в пути к сертификату?

Comment: Исключено. Во первых что в cli работает, во вторых что я его через realpath прогнал и на is_readable проверил в web версии

Comment: @Ninazu, вы же видите, что у вас разные версии PHP в листингах фигурируют? Ну и разные версии заголовочных файлов (наверное) OpenSSL.

Comment: @Ninazu, как следствие, проблема совсем не в том, что _в консоли все работает, а в вебе нет_, а в том, что **версия PHP** для веба имеет какие-то проблемы с (скорее всего) OpenSSL. Так что не стоит вводить всех в заблуждение.

Comment: Видел. Версии OpenSSL Header тоже. Устанавливал через 
`brew install php56`  чего они разные получились хз.
Если знаете как поставить одинаковые, был бы признателен